# How to setup time bounds for an escrow account?

Tags: java-sdk, stellar-sdk

I am trying to create 2-Party Multisignature Escrow Account with Time Lock & Recovery as in this ref:https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html

Now, I stuck at creating the time bound as in Transaction 3: Unlock and Transaction 4: Recovery

I had tried many possibilities for examples: addTimeBounds, addTime, TimeBounds, but none of them worked. I also looked here: https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/TimeBounds.html
And it still doesn't work.

Can anyone give me the example of code how I actually setup time bound?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work" means?

Answer (score 3):

Time bounds are part of the transaction itself, and are added in the Java SDK using the addTimeBounds method.

https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/Transaction.Builder.html#addTimeBounds-org.stellar.sdk.TimeBounds-

Here's an example for transaction 3:

```
SetOptionsOperation setOptionsOperation = new SetOptionsOperation.Builder()
      .setMasterKeyWeight(0)
      .setLowThreshold(1)
      .setMediumThreshold(1)
      .setHighThreshold(1)
      .build();

// set up the unlock date (there are lots of ways to do this)
Instant unlockDate = Instant.now().plusSeconds(60 * 120); // 2 hours from now
TimeBounds timeBounds = new TimeBounds(unlockDate.getEpochSecond(), 0);

// build the transaction and add the time bounds
Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
     .addOperation(setOptionsOperation)
     .addTimeBounds(timeBounds)
     .build();
```