# tx_too_early / Timebounds use

Tags: stellar-laboratory

I'm following [this tuto](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html) and I'm stuck at the part **Transaction 3: Unlock** (similar to [this question already asked](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/how-to-setup-time-bounds-for-an-escrow-account)).

**My understanding** : changing the thresholds to 1 when the minimum time is encountered.

**Usage** : On Stellar Laboratory, I try to make this transaction happens with a minimum timebound of my time + 2 hours.

**Result** : I get a status 400 and a tx_too_early

From my previous question [here](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/timebounds-wont-execute/1434#1434), I understand that timebounds only allow to valid a transaction at the time it is signed. Thus my questions are the following :

1. Is it even possible to automate a transaction to be executed at an exact time?
2. In case of an escrow, how do you handle the unlock automatically ? Do you have to do the step 3 at the time needed, can't you planify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Not as part of the Stellar protocol -- time bounds just specify when the transaction is considered valid. It doesn't have anything to do with how you actually submit them. A timebounds with time of now + 2 hours as the minimum simply means "I will be invalid if you submit me before 2 hours, but valid if you submit me after 2 hours". It's up to you to submit it at the given time.
2. Same as answer 1 -- just submit it after 2 hours via your own application's logic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on timed payments with Stellar. You can have a look at the testnet-version already: https://test.artspirit.com